# How can I test a jasper report?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jasper-reports

I want to test all the jasper reports of my application. I want to be able to detect:

- Compilation problems (Would checking that `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(some inputStream)` doesn´t throw `JRException` is a good option for this?)
- Filling problems (Would checking that `JasperFillManager.fillReport(someReport, someParameters, someDataSource)` doesn´t throw `JRException` is a good option for this?)
- Rendering problems: detect "null" strings appearing, text looking truncated in the exported PDF file
- Any other idea?

Ideally I would like to keep the testing process the most generic possible. The thing is that each jasper has a different data source so for detecting this errors i need to generate at list some data (right?) and this data I need to generate is different for each jasper of my application. So i don´t know how much testing code I  would be able to reuse. What approach would you take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For compilation problems and for filling problems: Yes, you can do as described and just try to compile and fill the report. If that does not throw an Exception, then you are fine.

For the third step of checking rendering problems, I export the report to XML:

```xml
String xml = JasperExportManager.exportReportToXml(
    JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, dataSource)
);
```

Theoretically the XML is an accurate representation of the PDF file, but in a format which is easy to read in tests. E.g. if a field is too long and the content is truncated, then it is also truncated in the XML. All values are already in the "rendered" format, so if you e.g. have a number that you format with a (DecimalFormat)-pattern, then the number will be formatted in the XML. Also the uuid-identifiers for fields are still present in the XML, so you can also easily find the fields. To check a field, you can e.g. do something along the lines of:

```java
hasXPath("//*[@uuid = '" + field.getUuid() + "']/../*[local-name() = 'textContent']", matcher)
```

Comment: That's a great idea! We can also export it as CSV via `JRCsvExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();`. This might be a little bit easier to work with although I've never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I created a couple of unit test for testing aspects.

1. Compilation problems: I created a class to load and compile all of my templates. My enviornment is web-based. So I tested the path through this as well.
2. For filling: I mocked data and JRDataSource to fill a template, that works find for me.
3. For Rendering: I haven't found a good approach to do it. Anyone got ideas?

And also, I usually use JavaBean data source so that I can test the reports using a traditional java unit test method.

Answer (score 1):

For compilation problems , one approach would be to use iReport tool and all report templates are compiles successfully; assuming that you are using templates and then populating data into it.

I found the following  link useful ,

http://flexingcode.blogspot.com/2009/04/junit-for-jasper-reports.html

Hope that helps,

Manju

Comment: Link is no longer available

Comment: Its on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150708140432/http://flexingcode.blogspot.com/2009/04/junit-for-jasper-reports.html), but the images are broken. You can still get the general idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

For automatic compilation you may try to compile reports with Ant script (see [1](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/antcompile/index.html) or http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/ant/package-summary.html)

Ant task is suitable to be used within automatic building or continuous integration system like maven or jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

One approach for the rendering could be to export the report to PDF and then use something like PDFBox (Apache) to test on the contents.
Also you could do the same with exporting to Excel file and then use Apache POI or JExcelAPI to test on the cell contents.

Regards

Fran

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the PDFbox approach to test the content of PDF documents: I just discovered the jPdfUnit opensource project which helps greatly:

Check out the docs here:
http://jpdfunit.sourceforge.net/docs/GettingStarted.html

It's based on junit 3 and hasen't been maintained in years, but it just works.
One tweak I had to apply to get it working was to set the pdfbox version to 1.8.13. Just put this in your  if you are using maven:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                <!-- jpdfunit is not compatible with pdfbox 2 (java5 vs java6) -->
                <version>1.8.13</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```